# agregar una columna dependiendo si existe o no en la sentencia

Tags: sql, sql-server, script

buenas estoy realizando una  consulta en sql server
que me muestra si no existe en ambas tablas que me lo traiga
y le agrege una columna con la tabla a la que pertenece.
estaba probando con algunas sentencias con if inner letf
pero no me da ningun resultado esperado
dejo un ejemplo de la sentencia.

```
SELECT A.id,B.id2,'' as tabla FROM tablaA as A
INNER JOIN tablaB as B
    ON (A.id != B.id2)
```

un ejemplo como deseo el resultado

```
_id_|__id2_______|_tabla_
null|   4        | A
8   |   null     | B
10  |   null     | B
null|   12       | A
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nunca se debe de utilizar una desigualdad como esa para unir dos tablas. Lo único que harás es generar una inmensidad de filas innecesarias. Esto se puede solucionar utilizando uno de los JOINs menos usados: el `FULL OUTER JOIN`.

Para traer solo las filas que no corresponden, agregamos las condiciones en el WHERE para que muestre las filas en las que no existan los datos en ambas tablas.

```
--Datos de Prueba
CREATE TABLE tablaA( id int);
INSERT INTO tablaA VALUES(1),(2),(3),(8),(10);
CREATE TABLE tablaB( id2 int);
INSERT INTO tablaB VALUES(1),(2),(3),(4),(12);

--Solución
SELECT A.id,
       B.id2, 
       IIF(A.id IS NULL, 'B', 'A') AS tabla 
FROM tablaA as A
FULL OUTER JOIN tablaB as B ON A.id = B.id2
WHERE A.id IS NULL
OR B.id2 IS NULL
ORDER BY ISNULL(A.id, B.id2);
```

Comment: Gracias. 
tomare de ahora en adelante lo que mencionas.
y sobre **FULL OUTER JOIN**  es verdad recien lo escucho.
gracias.

Answer (score -1):

Agregar una columna inexistente en consulta mysql

```
SELECT *, 'valor_predeterminado' AS nueva_columna 
FROM 'mi tabla'
```

Comment: Esa no fue la pregunta que ha hecho OP.